# Powershell Script needed to redact items in between separators in a row according to defined list

Tags: powershell, csv, replace, find

Hello and thanks for reading. It's my first post and really need some help. The hardest part is getting my question across in a way that people will understand. I will try my best.

I have some huge csv files (some in excess of 8 millions rows so Excel not an option really) where I need to modify the contents of the 3rd 'field' in each row according to sets of words defined in a reference file

So an example csv might be something like:

```
AB12|TEST|CAT DOG MOUSE|TEST1|TEST2|TEST3||TEST4

CD34|TEST|HORSE CART TRAIN|TEST1|TEST2|TEST3||TEST4
```

etc etc.

In my reference file I have a list eg:

```
CAT

HORSE CART
```

These are contained in a CSV

What I need is to modify the files so that the 3rd 'field' (everything after the 2nd'|' and before the 3rd '|' is compared to the reference list and modified to match. ie in the first line, everything after CAT would be deleted and in the second line, everything after HORSE CART would be deleted within this 3rd field. So the resultant file outputted would look like:

```
AB12|TEST|CAT|TEST1|TEST2|TEST3||TEST4

CD34|TEST|HORSE CART|TEST1|TEST2|TEST3||TEST4
```

I normally use F.A.R.T to modify large files, but this needs to be a bit more clever than FART is able to offer.

I really hope this makes sense to someone out there and appreciate any help you might offer.

So far I have been experimenting with this, but it's a long way off doing what I want:

```
cls

$content = ""

write-output "** Original String **"
write-output ""

$content = Get-Content "~\Desktop\Test\*.dat" 

$content

$separator1 = " " 
$separator2 = "|" 

$parts = $content.split($separator1)

write-output ""
write-output "** Revised String **"
write-output ""

$part1 = echo $parts[0]
$part3 = $part2.split($separator2)

$part4 = $part3[1]

$revised = $part1, $part4 -join "|"



$revised

write-output ""
```

So in summary then: This is really a modified 'Find and Replace Text' function that concentrates on a single field in each line, looks for matching sets of words, then deletes everything in that field other than the matched words, which are defined in a separate csv file.

Comment: So you have to test the third column against each of the reference values?

Comment: Correct. I am currently trying Find and Replace in Notepad++ but although I can do this across multiple large files, I can;t do more than one change at once. The reference file could have up to a thousand entries

Comment: So you’d need to check each rows 3rd column against a thousand items?

Comment: Potentially. If there was a way to do a multi line find and replace in NPP then this would do. 
However, because the list of changes is so large I don’t think this is an option.

Comment: Does the reference csv file (with the thousands of keywords in it) has headers, or is it simply a list of keywords each on a separate line?

Comment: Hi Theo, exactly right. 
Just a huge list.

Comment: An added complication. The reference list might contain one or two words (or even 3) one of which is a word which appears on its own elsewhere. 
So ‘HORSE CART’ might be there but ‘HORSE’ may also be there. So the order that the list appears in is crucial. However I can handle that. 
If only excel could handle 8 million entries. Then using remove duplicates would be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as comparing arrays in PowerShell doesn't support wild cards we have to do this the old fashioned (costly) way. Compare every field with every reference.

I've not provided an example of reading the file as that can be done in different ways with regards to speed or memory consumption (your choice).

Also, I've provided the reference as an array instead as a file input to keep the example to the point (and easily testable).

The output should then of course be done to a new file instead of written to the host.

```
$file = @"
F1|F2|F3|F4|F5|F6|F7|F8
AB12|TEST|CAT DOG MOUSE|TEST1|TEST2|TEST3||TEST4
CD34|TEST|HORSE CART TRAIN|TEST1|TEST2|TEST3||TEST4
CD34|TEST|HORSE CART|TEST1|TEST2|TEST3||TEST4
"@

$ref = @("CAT*","HORSE CART*")


$file.split("`n") | foreach {# line in file
    $outline = $nul
    $_.split('|') | foreach {# field in the line
        $field = $_
        $refhit = $false
        $ref | foreach {# item in the ref array
            if ($field -like $_) {# replace field with ref
                $refhit = $true
                $outline += $_.TrimEnd('*') + '|'
            }# end match
            
        }# end ref

        if (!$refhit){#pass on the field as is
            $outline += "$field|" 
        }
        
    }#end field

    # Output filtered line
    write-host $outline.TrimEnd('|')

}#end line
```

Comment: Hi Dennis and thank you very much for taking a look at this. Can I clarify a few things?

Comment: Hi Dennis and thank you very much for taking a look at this. Can I clarify a few things?
1. When you say that powershell doesn't handle wildcards, what then is the purpose of the * in the reference array? (CAT*)
2. Is there any way of only comparing the 3rd segment of the main file as this is the only field that will need to be altered.
3. Memory isn't a problem, so I'd be grateful if you could add a couple of lines showing the best way to read the entire file into memory (and also the reference file) and then the best way of outputting to a new file. 

Sorry I know so little. Thanks

Comment: 1. PowerShell array comparision doesn't handle wild cards. Ordinary item by item comparison does.
2. Instead of piping all fields you can assign an array to $_.Split('|'). $fields = $_.Split('|'). Then fields[2] will get you the third field. But that will add to memory consumption.
3. The just use $file = get-content <your_path>

Comment: Hi Dennis - thanks. One last thing.
$ref | foreach {# item in the ref array
            if ($field -like $_) {# replace field with ref
                $refhit = $true
                $outline += $_.TrimEnd('*') + '|'

Once a match in the ref file has been found, I'd like to terminate the foreach and move on to the next field in the original file. Break or Continue appears not to work
Any clues?

Comment: In that case you need to use a foreach ($field in $array) {...} instead of using a pipe for the array. But pipes are generally much faster anyhow :)
There is no way to abort part of a stream in a pipe (I think that feature will be available in PoSH 7.1).

Comment: Please consider accepting this as the answer by clicking the check mark. You can always change it later if someone offers a better answer.